appscript to move checked rows to another sheet when clicked custom menu item in google sheets

As seen in the picture i have 2 sheets. I need the appscript code for the following.

I need to create a custom menu as seen in the image.
When Move to Done is clicked, the checked rows should get appended to the Done sheet.
The checked rows should also be deleted from the pending sheet.

sheet link

Look at UI.createMenu commands.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu

But if there is data in C, D columns that is also need to be moved. How can i achieve that? A note for future reference: It's important to draft the original question to include ALL relevant information. If one could anticipate that there would be data in Columns C and D that should be included in the "copy" then it is more appropriate that this should go in the original question than asked as a followup.

Move data from one sheet to another
I have crafted a solution that you may try to get your expected result.
How this code works:

The code will validate the values in column A that are "checked" or set to "TRUE"
All of the values of these checkboxes will be moved to the "completed" sheet.
The moved values will be deleted in the "pending" sheet.

To meet your requirements of having a custom menu, please run the onOpen() function
Completed code:
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('New Menu')
    .addItem('Move to Done', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pending = ss.getSheetByName('pending');
  var completed = ss.getSheetByName('completed');
  
  var pendingData = pending.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values = [];

  for (var i = pendingData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (pendingData[i][0] === true) {
      values.push([pendingData[i][1], pendingData[i][2], pendingData[i][3]]);
      pending.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
  completed.getRange(completed.getLastRow() + 1, 2, values.length, 3).setValues(values.reverse());
}

Sample output:

Reference:
Custom Menu

If you have any questions with regards to the answer posted above, please do not hesitate to leave a comment. So, I can adjust the code accordingly.

Your solution works fine. Thanks a lot. But if there is data in C, D columns that is also need to be moved.  How can i achieve that?

Kindly check my updated answer and see if it met your expected result. I have specified the Column B, C, and D to be moved to the other sheet.
